# UIWebView Compiler asking for a IBOutlet that i don't use Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, webview

I re-re edit my question : it's for about two weeks that i set up my WebView in my application, everything was going well working together. Yesterday i wanted to just see if the webView is still working even if i didn't change any of the class's code, and boom SIGABRT. So  today i decided to change my UIWebView to a programmatically coded WebView. The problem is xcode is still asking for a IBOutlet that i don't use :O. If someone with advanced objective c skills could help me i'm going crazy.
Log message : `

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "MyWebView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'`
here is my code :



       - (void)showWebView;
        {
            //here i call my webview in my RootViewController
            ViewController *WebViewVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];
            [[self navigationController] pushViewController:WebViewVC  animated:YES];
            [WebViewVC pushIt];

        }

    //here is my WebViewController.h
            #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
            #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

        @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
        {
             //IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;
             UIWebView *newWeb;
        }

        //@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;
        -(void)XButton;
        -(void)pushIt;
        @end


        //here is my WebViewController.m
            -(void)pushIt;
        {



  self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;


        self.title = @"*****";
        self.title = @"Endosize";
newWeb = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:newWeb];
[self XButton];
[self WebViewBrowserBackButton];

        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *defaults = [prefs stringForKey:@"myKey"];
        NSString *defaults2 = [prefs stringForKey:@"mySecondKey"];
        NSString *username = defaults; 
        NSString *password = defaults2;
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"**************"]; 
        NSString* body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"************",      username,     password];  
        NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
        request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
        request.HTTPBody = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];

        [newWeb loadRequest:request];
    }
```

Comment: The .xib file of your parent view controller has probably a UIWebView connected. Remove that connection and try running the app again.

Comment: You guessed well :D, i did erase everything in my parent view that has anything to do with a WebView but still get that nasty SIGABRT :O. any clues or solutions please. (Thank you for the answer :) ).

Comment: I wrote my comment as an answer, so you can accept it if you like :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concern, but it didn't work :( if i get no other best answer be sure i will rate you as the good answer, if you will edit an answer, in order to help people struggling with code here ^^.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIWebView "SIGABRT" in Objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926277/uiwebview-sigabrt-in-objective-c)

Comment: Please stop re-asking the same question. Edit your original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .xib file of your parent view controller has probably a UIWebView connected. Remove that connection and try running the app again.

Comment: That's it i found the reason why it wasn't working :D, i just erased the derived data and bang everything gets working as usual. :D !